# Why my Gmail app keep hang up?

Tags: gmail

For about three months, Gmail started to hang up whenever I tried to compose or reply to emails. I thought battery optimization was the problem, so I made Gmail not restricted by any battery optimization but the problem remains. I also tried removing updates, clearing the cache, and reinstalling updates again.

The problem occurred in two devices, one is Android 10 and the other is Android 13.

Any advice?